# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net

Здравствуйте!

Не могу разобраться с одной ошибкой. Когда я пытаюсь из `List` вытянуть инфу в `DataGridView`, выскакивает это:

> Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта

[image: это мой контроллер]

Comment: И что вам непонятно в тексте сообщения?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow - я не могу понять как это исправить(

Comment: Нужно создать объект, чтобы соответствующая ссылка не была нулевой.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow так я это все сделал

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow я так и делаю                                                        
<!-- language-all: c#                   
public class CrewController
    {
        private ICrewService _crewService;


        public CrewController(Form1 form, ICrewService crewService)
        {
            _crewService = crewService; -->

Comment: Просто проверьте значения  аргумента crewService при вызове конструктора  и члена класса _crewService при вызове метода, где возникло исключение.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow у меня ниже в коде используется _crewService для Добавления Изменения и Удаления и там все нормально, а здесь почему выдает исключение(

Comment: Отследите значение этого члена класса, просто распечатывая его с момента инициализации в конструкторе.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow действительно у меня один конструктор с параметрами один без и тот что без параметров не инициализирует _crewService так как он заполняет DataGridView перед запуском формы и я туда не передаю интерфейс ICrewService